# How to manage multiple usernames in Express JS?

Tags: node.js, express

I have been working on a real-time chat application since weeks. First I used PHP as my back-end language but I was uncomfortable with it, so I switched to Node.js. I am using ExpressJS. But, now I have a problem. I have a page where the website asks for user to enter his/her name. ( let's say our website is **localhost:8080**, after submit is clicked, the information ( name here ) is posted to **localhost:8080/register** ) So, in the back-end I do ( consider express is already required while app = express() )  :

```
app.post('/register', (req, res) => {
  var name = req.body.name // assuming the variable containg the username was **name**
  // So, from here I can use the username any where I want
})
```

But, the problem is if another person enters his/her, then all the names of the users on the server gets changed by the name of the user who entered last. So, what should I do to keep their names unique ? My platform : Windows 10 PRO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a couple capabilities here:

1. When a user registers a username, you need to save it somehow so that it will be associated with any future requests from that particular browser.
2. You need to be able to support multiple users independently.
3. You need to be able to prevent duplicate usernames from different users.

This means you cannot store a username in a module level or global variable because then it would be used by all incoming connections and that's not what you want.

The usual means for doing something like this with Express is to use express-session.  This will automatically set a cookie for any incoming request and then give to you an object where you can store data for that user.  Each time that user makes a request to your server, their browser will send the session cookie and express-session can look up that session cookie and find the data object that goes with that user.

You would then use that object to first set the username and then on later requests to get the user name for that particular user.  From then on (until the session expires), anytime that user makes a request to your server, you can look in the session object to see what their username is.  You can put other user-specific data in that session object too.

When using the default memory-based storage mechanism, express-session is very easy to use and you can see examples in [the doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session).

Then, you may also need some sort of list of users (perhaps just in memory or perhaps in more persistent storage, depending upon your needs) so you can make sure when someone picks a new name that nobody else is using that name.

Answer (score -2):

If you are using same machine to enter name then I think server will take last name, if you use different machine to enter name then server might take different names.